# JS Chart library that allows partial shading of the y axis

Tags: javascript, charts

I've been looking around for a line chart library that allows you to shade one or more sections of the y axis to display an acceptable range for the value being graphed. Something similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khXOM.jpg)

I've used Google Charts on past project & searched through documentation for various libraries found via Google (chart.js, c3.js, nvd3.js...) and none of them seem to support it. So I'm wondering if anyone has a recommendation.

Comment: Have you checked out Highcharts?

Comment: Haven't looked at HighCharts yet, checking it out now, I actually just came back to this tab because I found one that comes close MorrisJS allows specifying the color of individual lines on the Y axis which might be good enough https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The library [Zingchart](http://www.zingchart.com) could handle what you are trying to achieve through labels and markers. You can set an area or line marker around a specific range of value points, and set styling to that marker. Labels (for your A,B,C labels) are placed on an x/y coordinate scale and can be modified accordingly.

I'm on the ZingChart team and will be more than happy to help with any further questions.

```js
var myConfig = {
  type: "line", 
  labels : [
    {
      x : "15%",
      y : "15%",
      fontSize : 18,
      text : "ZONE"
    },
    {
      x : "15%",
      y : "25%",
      fontSize : 18,
      text : "A"
    },
      {
      x : "15%",
      y : "34%",
      fontSize : 18,
      text : "B"
    },
    {
      x : "15%",
      y : "42%",
      fontSize : 18,
      text : "C"
    },
    {
      x : "15%",
      y : "50%",
      fontSize : 18,
      text : "C"
    },
      {
      x : "15%",
      y : "59%",
      fontSize : 18,
      text : "B"
    },
      {
      x : "15%",
      y : "68%",
      fontSize : 18,
      text : "A"
    },
  ],
  scaleY : {
    values : "-100:100:10",
    markers : [
      {
        type : 'line',
        range : [75],
        lineWidth : 2,
        lineStyle : "dotted",
        lineColor : "#ff2424"
      },
      {
        type : 'area',
        range : [50,75],
        alpha : 0.6,
        backgroundColor : "#ff7171"
      },
      {
        type : 'area',
        range : [25,50],
        alpha : 0.6,
        backgroundColor : "#fdff71"
      },
      {
        type : 'area',
        range : [0,25],
        alpha : 0.6,
        backgroundColor : "#98ff71"
      },
      {
        type : 'line',
        range : [0],
        lineWidth : 2,
        lineStyle : "dotted",
        lineColor : "#006dff"
      },
      {
        type : 'area',
        range : [0,-25],
        alpha : 0.6,
        backgroundColor : "#98ff71"
      },
      {
        type : 'area',
        range : [-25,-50],
        alpha : 0.6,
        backgroundColor : "#fdff71"
      },
      {
        type : 'area',
        range : [-50,-75],
        alpha : 0.6,
        backgroundColor : "#ff7171"
      },
      {
        type : 'line',
        range : [-75],
        lineWidth : 2,
        lineStyle : "dotted",
        lineColor : "#ff2424"
      }
    ]
  },
  
 series : [
  {
   values : [2,4,4,25,36,14,23,23,24,25,16,8],
  }
 ]
};
 
zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 400, 
 width: 600 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
    </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```